# A Python Arithmetic Math Game

Tags: python

Minor information: I am using a Lenovo Chromebook (Linux), CodePad (Text Editor), and Terminal (as a way to see the output).

Objective: I wanted to create a game-like program, where the computer generates random values between 0 to a 100 and generates a random operator, to add/subtract/multiply/divide with another random value between 0 to a 100. If you get the question correct, your score goes up by 1 and if it's wrong your score decreases by 1.

**Problem**: The program works good on all the operators except division. I want the division answer to be rounded to the nearest hundredths. For example: 23 / 54 = 0.42592592592. I want the program to accept it as 0.43.

Here's what I have:    *(Can someone edit my code below to Python, I'm not sure how).*

```
from random import randint
import random
score = 0
while True:
    num1 = randint(0,100)
    num2 = randint(0,100)
    op = random.choice(["+", "-", "*", "/"])

    if op == '+':
        print(num1, "+", num2, "= x ")
        x_answer = num1 + num2

    elif op == '-':
        print(num1, '-', num2, '= x')
        x_answer = num1 - num2

    elif op == '*':
        print(num1, "*", num2, "= x")
        x_answer = num1 * num2

    elif op == "/":
        print(num1, "/", num2, "= x")
        x_answer = num1 / num2

    else:
        print("Invalid Operator")


    x = float(input("What's x? "))


    if x == x_answer:
        score += 1 
        print("CORRECT, your score is:", score)
    
    elif x != x_answer:
        score -= 1
        print("INCORRECT, you lost a point! Current score:", score)
```

Again, just to reiterate the problem: when there's a division question, the answer has to be the entire thing (example: 0.432...) I want the computer to accept 0.43 as the answer and let the score go up if 0.43 is the answer.

Comment: So the question is how to compare floating point numbers to a fixed precision? And we don't really need all that other stuff, right?

Comment: Well, I just wanted to know how I could have the computer accept a rounded number as the answer (for division). Currently it accepts the entire answer (ex: 0.32424523). I want the computer to accept it as (0.32).  By accept, what I mean is having the score to go up by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the built in `round()` function in python around the float value, like so:

```
elif op == "/":
    print(num1, "/", num2, "= x")
    x_answer = round(float(num1 / num2), 2)
```

The first value in the `round()` function gives the value to round and the second tell python to what decimal place. In this example you want to the 2 decimal, so put 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
# this is a unit test for a comparison function f
def test(f):
    # check the case where it should be rounded down
    expected = 0.432
    correct = 0.43
    wrong = 0.44
    if not f(expected, correct):
        raise ValueError
    if f(expected, wrong):
        raise ValueError

    # check the case where it should be rounded up
    expected = 0.437
    correct = 0.44
    wrong = 0.43
    if not f(expected, correct):
        raise ValueError
    if f(expected, wrong):
        raise ValueError

    # need to accept more precision if it's right
    if not f(expected, expected):
        raise ValueError

    print ('passed')

places = 2

# floating point comparison by delta
def equivalent_delta(x, y):
    delta = 5 * 10 ** - (places+1)
    return abs(x-y) < delta

# comparison using builtin function round
def equivalent_round(x, y):
    return round(x, places) == round(y, places)

# compare their string representation with 2 places
def equivalent_print(x, y):
    format_string = '{{:.{}}}'.format(places)
    return format_string.format(x) == format_string.format(y)

# multiply by 100, convert to integer (with 0.5 for rounding)   
def equivalent_as_int(x, y):
    return int(x * 10**places + 0.5) == int(y * 10**places + 0.5)

test(equivalent_delta)
test(equivalent_round)
test(equivalent_print)
test(equivalent_as_int)
```

see also [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)